# PDF report layout broken using setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4) QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt, printing, qprinter

I was using the following code to set the paper size of my **QPrinter** object:

```
printer_.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
```

On my computer, it is working as expected, but on another computer, my PDF report layout is "broken".

Searching for the reason of that, I found this issue:
[Qt QPrinter setPaperSize does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881382/qt-qprinter-setpapersize-does-not-work-properly)

Like @Jens said: *"setPaperSize relies on information received from the printer driver..."*.

I checked the `QPrinter::A4` size on **Qt documentation** and its size corresponds to **210 x 297 mm**.

Can I just change the **setPaperSize** parameters from: `printer_.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);` to `printer_.setPaperSize(QSizeF(210, 297), QPrinter::Millimeter);`?
Will it work properly (printer independent)?

I am asking it because I don't have the other computer to test it anymore, and I can't reproduce the problem on my computer. By the way, if anyone knows how can I reproduce the problem on my computer to test if the issue was solved, I appreciate.

Example:
[image]

The black border on images is used only to show the boundaries of the printed area.

**Note**: I am using Qt 5.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the **setPaperSize** parameters from:

```
printer_.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
```

to:

```
printer_.setPaperSize(QSizeF(210, 297), QPrinter::Millimeter);
```

The values **210** and **297** are from the **Qt** Documentation:

> "QPrinter::A4 - 0 - 210 x 297 mm, 8.26 x 11.69 inches"

Basically, instead of getting the size from the printer device using `QPrinter::A4`, I am setting a fixed `QSizeF` based on the correct **A4** millimeters size.

It worked for me.